# How to play video linked in Blob URL?

Tags: ios, swift, url, video-streaming, blob

I have a video linked in video tag like this: `src="blob:http://www.domain.com/884f-ff99697a3a91"`

So are there any ways for me to play the video in iOS app? I tried to build a html5 page with video tag and use a webView to load the page but nothing happens.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, a Blob URL acts as a pseudo protocol to enable using Blobs as if they where byte-streams. They would not make sense in any other context as the original Blob they're referring to would not be available.

The temporary internal link to the Blob (or File) becomes invalid once the original document creating it is unloaded (or the URL revoked).

You would need a way to load the original video source directly, which would either require an user interaction if from a local file system, or the video must exist online and be referable via an ordinary URL.

Comment: Okay, sounds makes sense to me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
 - (void)videoThumb:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
      NSString *embedHTML = @"\
      <html><head>\
      <style type=\"text/css\">\
      body {\
      background-color: transparent;
      color: white;
      }\
      </style>\
      </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
      <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
      width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
      </body></html>";


     NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width,frame.size.height];

    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView release];
}
```

Comment: It don't think it works. I've tried and see nothing happens.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean @EricAya?